# After upgrading to 20.04 my GNOME session dies constantly. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, asus

I know my Asus laptop is not the best for Linux. I've had problems with all previous versions of Ubuntu, but only with suspend/resume. I was randomly unable to resume after being suspended.

However, things got worse from 20.04. My Gnome session dies in two to three days. Now, when I work from home, I do the same routine every day: Firefox for personal affairs, Chrome for work-related work, Citrix Workspace for remote access, Nautilus and sometimes LibreOffice.

Everything looks good after a new login. After a few hours, mouse and keyboard response will slow down. After a day or two, I face periodical freezes up to 10-20 minutes.The hard drive light is always on and it looks like a heavy swap is taking place. If I am able to switch to a virtual terminal, I see that either Firefox or Chrome is consuming CPU. But gradually gnome-shell starts to outpace the CPU consumption. Finally, the session freezes completely, and my laptop is not registered on the network anymore.

To rule out hardware issues, I spent two weeks by using Windows 10 on my laptop. I didn't have any problem. Just once closing the lid did not let the laptop sleep. Opening a lot of pages in browsers slows down the response, but in any case, the response time on Windows is always acceptable.

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

I added the required information

```
$ free -h
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         7.6Gi       4.7Gi       712Mi       1.6Gi       2.2Gi       1.0Gi
Swap:        2.0Gi       1.6Gi       427Mi
```

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 yury yury 4096 May  1 17:34 .
drwx------ 4 yury yury 4096 Sep 12 14:03 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 yury yury 4096 May  9 23:10 glassygnome@emiapwil
drwxr-xr-x 2 yury yury 4096 Jun 29 21:30 lockkeys@fawtytoo
```

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan  9  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 18 09:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 18 09:54 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May  8 19:00 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 29 14:57 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
X556UQ.315
```

It is original ASUS X556U laptop. The laptop has two graphic cards:

```
$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
```

Previously I always had problems with nouveau, so I installed propitiatory NVIDIA drivers.

[image: screen shot of top]

Gnome extensions
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me  the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema OP added the needed info--just making sure you got them

Comment: @EarthToAccess Thanks for the assist!

Comment: When you provide more info at the request from a comment, please assure that you notify the requester that you've done so, otherwise they'll miss your updates.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I also believe it is a swap problem.  I can change swap size and update BIOS  only tonight after I will finish work. Just to be safe asI am working from home using this laptop. I will update you immediately. Thanks again! Yury

Comment: 1) SWAP:  I resized the swap file to make it 8.0Gi (to enable hibernation to the swap file later).
2) BIOS:  I put off updating the BIOS for a while. I'll do a little research before doing this. 
3) GNOME Shell extensions: glassygnome is disabled. So, I have only lockkeys which I definitely need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a larger swapfile will resolve browsers slow down. But, please,
give me at least a week to make sure that Gnome session is stable. Then I will fully accept your answer. 
Thanks, Yury

Comment: Sure enough! Please remember to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: @yurad Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the root cause of my Gnome crashing. This was caused by NVIDIA drivers. Before I caught it, I ran into several regular gnome shell errors that caused Gnome to crash. An invalid desktop file on the desktop was simply causing Gnome to crash more often than other errors. I also ran into slowness in web browsers. Investigation of these errors pointed to NVIDIA driver errors. I did install NVIDIA drivers after updating to 20.04. The fact is that my laptop has two video cards: onboard Intel and a dedicated GeForce 940MX. Nouveau never worked with the GeForce 940MX and couldn't stop the card. I've always had occasional suspend/resume and even shutdown issues, but I've never run into issues with a working GUI session . After the 20.04 update, I could only suspend/resume from the virtual terminal and I installed the NVIDIA drivers. All suspend/resume issues were resolved, but I got into a nightmare loop due to Gnome crashes and slow browsers. NVIDIA drivers also do not work with the GeForce 940MX. So I stopped the NVIDIA card and all my errors went away. Gnome-shell does not take up the processor and stops crashing. I even restored the wrong desktop file on the Desktop and it does not cause any problem anymore. The battery lasts significantly longer. Ironically, the best way to disable (stop) an NVIDIA card that is not supported by NVIDIA drivers is to install the NVIDIA drivers. With the drivers, NVIDIA supplies the nvidia-settings utility
(NVIDIA X Server Setting)  that allows us to stop NVIDIA cards by selecting the onboard card as the GPU to use.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have a swap problem.

**SWAP**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**BIOS**

ASUS X556U

You have BIOS version X556UQ.315.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 316, from 6/6/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/ph/Laptops/ASUS-Vivobook-X556UQ/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**GNOME Shell extensions**

Very good. You don't have a ton of GNOME Shell extensions.

You have:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 yury yury 4096 May  9 23:10 glassygnome@emiapwil
drwxr-xr-x 2 yury yury 4096 Jun 29 21:30 lockkeys@fawtytoo
```

If you still have trouble, try and disable these and see if things improve.

**Update #1:**

An invalid .desktop file was found on ~/Desktop. After removing this file, the problem(s) have not been seen again.

Comment: Unfortunately, we didn't have to wait a week. My gnome session hung yesterday as always after two days of work. Increasing the swapfile file helped in only two ways: the browser slowdown was noticeable, but not as much as before, and after gnome-shell took all the CPY, it became easier to switch to virtual terminals. The GUI session hung when I was doing an emergency investigation at midnight and it was hard to endure.

Comment: I had typical symptoms in this case: I could move the mouse pointer, but neither clicking nor pressing the keys worked. The GUI session was unresponsive, I just could use the ctrl + alt + F keys to switch between virtual terminals and frozen GUI. "DISPLAY =: 0 gnome-shell -r &" didn't help. I didn't have time to research and I restarted my laptop.

Comment: To be honest, it didn't surprise me that my problem persisted. The 2 G swapfile never caused problems prior to 20.04. I was able to work with two instances of Android Studio, with dozens of tabs in browsers, and I don't remember any significant slowdown. It was only once every couple of weeks that I could not resume after suspend. I upgraded to 20.04 mainly due to the built-in fractional scaling support. On my laptop, scaling via experimental features was buggy. However, I previously tried to disable fractional scaling and still the Gnome session would hang after a few days.

Comment: @yurad Try two things... disable lockkeys, and once a day, do ALT-F2, then r, then ENTER, to restart GNOME Shell. See if either helps. Show me a screenshot of `top` when you're running your normal apps. Did you do the BIOS yet? Report back.

Comment: "disable lockkeys" - I wanted to, but I cannot! My both extensions look unavailable. When? Why? I can't enable them anymore. Another Gnome glitch? "restart GNOME Shell" is a good idea. It's acceptable to me, but, this is only a workaround. "top" - I attached a screenshot to my question. "BIOS" - not yet. Waiting for ASUS support. I don't see upgrade option in the BIOS.   I also disabled fractional scaling again. I need display scaling but I wanted to test again. Maybe combined with a big SWAP it will help.

Comment: @yurad I didn't quite understand your gnome shell extension problem. How are you trying to disable/enable them. Tweaks, Firefox, or something else? Try https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ in Firefox. Report back.

Comment: re: "disable lockkeys - extensions look unavailable." . I figured it out. It's a confusing interface of GUI extension manager. The switch to disable/enable extensions is inside the window bar without any label. Apparently after I disabled fractional scaling , manual extensions were switched off, but I didn't noticed it.  I checked the installation date of the lockkeys. Definitely  lockkeys could be causing my problem. If successful, I'll let you know in a week.

Comment: Quick update. Disabling extensions didn't help. Restarting gnome-shell (alt F2 r) every time Gnome started to crash helped me keep my work open for a week, which is good. Also, I am making progress in understanding what is wrong with my Gnome. However, I will not share this information right now because I had the opportunity to update the BIOS and I will be watching Gnome's behavior for a few more days. Then I will write a final comment. Thanks!

Comment: @yurad Thanks for the update. Keep me posted so I can update my answer.

Comment: BIOS update. This did not fix Gnome crashing. I was skeptical about updating the BIOS because before "20.04" Gnome had no problem with the old BIOS. Also in Windows 10 there were no problems. However, I see some improvements with the new BIOS, the degradation in Gnome has been slower. The crash happened 2-3 days later. Unless it was a coincidence.

Comment: I looked closely at the symptoms again. At first, gnome took up more CPU, and at the same time, mouse and key reactions became slower. Then I saw various problems with Gnome, and finally Gnome just stopped working. Immediately after I noticed the slowness of Gnome, I examined the syslog and found several messages with "JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties" etc. There were no such messages before the slowness began. As the Gnome shell increased CPU utilization, the number of these errors in the syslog increased dramatically. Most likely, these are accumulated errors.

Comment: This is a bug and I found relevant reports. There are two of  then: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1841774  and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1752923 .I  haven't researched in more detail.

Comment: Luckily, my Gnome session is getting worse gradually. I can manage to notice the symptoms and restart the Gnome shell. Restarting at the very beginning does not take much time and practically does not affect my work. So this workaround allows me to keep using Gnome instead of switching to KDE or even Windows.
I'm not sure if I should accept your answer or only mark it as "useful." The issue has not been resolved, but the restart advice is very practical.

Comment: @yurad Do me a favor. Do `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*` and upload that output to paste.ubuntu.com, then ping me, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @yurad You never disabled BOTH glassygnome@emiapwil and lockkeys@fawtytoo
GNOME Shell extensions, correct?

Comment: Hi, heynnema., I pasted lines from syslog.   Shell  extensions:  Manual extensions are still turned off. You can see the screenshot appended to my question.

Comment: "@heynnema"  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KvkwWvV3Cj/
I also copied from syslog.2.gz
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mVByNPchSv/
and from Sep 22 -23
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kqWkSqr4Pz/
where I see "message repeated 1638 times: [ JS ERROR: TypeError:..."
Another thing to mention, I have enabled icons on Desktop. The old school...

Comment: In addition, I am unable to Start comments  with "@heynnema" . Stack Exchange removes your ID, probably because this is a comment on your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113757/discussion-between-heynnema-and-yurad).

Comment: Indeed this "JS ERROR: TypeError: null has no properties" messages were caused by an invalid desktop file located on the Desktop. Since I removed the file two weeks ago, I never encountered this problem. There are no such messages in syslog. gnome-shell does not require significant CPU resources anymore. I have not seen any significant Gnome glitches and crashes. Even web browsers have stopped degrading performance.So, the problem can be marked as solved. Will you just update your answer or should I answer my own question? Also, obviously this is a gnome-shell bug. How to report it?

Comment: @yurad I updated my answer. Good job on the find!